# Awkward word/line breaks in Firefox

Tags: firefox, whitespace, word-wrap, word-break

I am getting awkward word/line breaks sitewide in Firefox at

[trac3.com](http://192.185.29.116/~trac3/)

I have read numerous threads here and elsewhere in search of an answer. I've tried seemingly endless combinations of white-space, word-wrap, word-break and hyphen, but with no success. I don't know that I can really provide any code, seeing as it is happening everywhere on the site.

Again, this appears to be a Firefox issue.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the 'inspect element' window and removed the following line from `.post .post-excerpt`. This fixed it for me

```
-moz-hyphens: auto;
```

Hope this helps

Edit: I also added `word-break: initial;`. This is also important.

Comment: Yes, that's it! ... Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad that fixed it. Sometimes it's the little things that give you the most trouble